# Semantic UI - Error While Importing Gulp Tasks

Tags: gulp, semantic-ui

I am trying to import Semantic UI's Gulp tasks into my own Gulpfile. I want my parent Gulp file to run Semantic's 'gulp build' command, then have my parent Gulp copy the files Semantic's build command outputs to another folder. Everything was moving along until I hit this error:

> Error: Task build-javascript is not configured as a task on gulp.  If this is a submodule, you may need to use `require('run-sequence').use(gulp)`.

I have a folder /semantic/ which includes all the tasks and everything. And my gulpfile is setup just like Semantic's docs recommend. http://semantic-ui.com/introduction/advanced-usage.html

```
var watchUI     = require('./semantic/tasks/watch'),
    buildUI     = require('./semantic/tasks/build')
```

Has anybody else run into this problem?  Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an open issue on github. But this instructions helped me:
https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/4374#issuecomment-236729805

> 1. Open the file `node_modules/semantic-ui/tasks/install.js` in your preferred text editor.
> 2. On line 26, you should see `runSequence = require('run-sequence'),`. Please replace it with `runSequence = require('run-sequence').use(gulp),`
> 3. Run in the console `cd node_modules/semantic-ui && gulp install`.